# Evaluate mathematical expression inside string

Tags: python, regex

My question is very simple, suppose I have a string like `s = 'line $sin(2*x) $x*cos(x) $x'` and I know the value of `x` (1.0 for example) from somewhere else. Now I want to evaluate the string so it becomes something like `s = line 0.909 -0.416 1.0'`. You can see that there are three mathematical expressions in string s: each begins with $ symbol and ends with either space or end-of-line.

The idea should be simple: use regular expressions and `re.sub` function. I knew nothing about regex before, and after one or two hours I know the basic of it, but still can't figure out how to get a proper pattern to match the three expressions, each on its own. If I succeed at this, the remaining part is simple, evaluate the expression using eval(), convert to string, and assemble the whole string to be returned. The code I came up with is below.

```
import re
from math import *

# parameters
x = 1.0
# test strings
s = 'line $sin(2*x) $x*cos(x) $x'

p = '\$[\s+]'

def replacer(s):
    if s.startswith('$'):
        return eval(s[1:])
    else:
        return "ERROR"

print re.sub(p,replacer,s)
```

I am sure the regular expression is wrong because it does not capture the three patterns, I experimented many times with different patterns... Can somebody helps me get a working pattern? Then I think I can proceed with the rest.
Update: problem solved, see the selected answer below.

Comment: `\s` is the metacharacter for whitespace...

Comment: Okay. And your problem is? You didn't ask anything!

Comment: @alKid The problem is that the code is not working, the regular expression I wrote must be wrong. I want to match, for example, each of the three expression: $sin(2*x) and $x*cos(x) and $x, and evaluate them with the x value (1.0) I have. I have worked as much as I can to get the code above, but I can't proceed further, that's why I am here to ask for help.

Comment: @Dannnno Someone on the internet says it's all non-whitespace character, I will check that...

Comment: Do you want `r'\$\S+'`?

Comment: Taozi I think you were trying to mention @VasiliSyrakis there

Comment: @Dannnno You are right... I am a registered user of SO for the first time, my apology.

Comment: @SethMMorton You are absolutely right!

Comment: @bgporter Dear all, I've updated my question and made it clearer, could you lift the hold on my question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are using `[\s+]` in your regex, which will match whitespace or the + sign only once.
The proper expression you want is `\$(\S+)` which puts everything except the $ sign into a capture group for later use.

Secondly, you need to start coding Python in a pythonic way. Putting random variables all over the place with your values and expression lines is not reusable.
Instead, encapsulate repetitive variables inside the scope of a function. It will be less headache in the longterm.

The regex function that you need in this instance is not `re.sub` but `re.findall`. This function iterates through ALL the matches in a string.

You will notice that I compiled the regex before using it, this just allows for cleaner code in this instance.

Finally, we loop through an extremely simple `list()` data type of our regex matches.

As you can see, you can simply call the `evaluate_expression()` function on ANY expression and ANY value.

```
import re
from math import *


def evaluate_expression(equation, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        exec key + " = " + str(kwargs[key])  # Creates x variable
    parser = re.compile(r'\$(\S+)')
    expressions = parser.findall(equation)
    for expression in expressions:
        print eval(expression)

evaluate_expression('line $sin(2*x) $x*cos(x) $x', x=1.0)
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and much appreciated, I can learn a lot from it - not just for this specific problem. I wish I can upvote your answer but currently I don't have enough reputation (especially with the downvotes on my question :-( ), so I will do that later. Thanks!

Comment: No problems. I even learnt something new by answering this. I didn't know how to use `**kwargs` 20 minutes ago.